# Adding grid unit objects

Tags: r, r-grid

So the setup is this:

```
dat <- data.frame(a = c("longnameonthelefthandside"), b = c(sample(10))) 
p <- ggplot(dat, aes(b,a)) + geom_point() + xlab("label")
```

I can adjust the x axis label by passing a `unit` object to `hjust`:

```
p + opts(axis.title.x=theme_text(size=12,hjust=unit(0.3,"npc")))
```

But there's something about adding unit objects (possible, according to ?unit) that I'm not grasping:

```
u1 <- unit(0.5,"npc")
u2 <- unit(0.25,"npc")
p + opts(axis.title.x=theme_text(size=12,hjust=u1+u2))
```

yields the following error:

```
Error in grid.Call("L_textBounds", as.graphicsAnnot(x$label), x$x, x$y,  : 
Polygon edge not found
In addition: Warning message:
In validDetails.text(x) : NAs introduced by coercion
```

As further context, I'm trying to piece together a somewhat cryptic workaround via Baptiste [here](http://groups.google.com/group/ggplot2/browse_thread/thread/86e6e831b149db/6c5419340d308e34?lnk=gst&q=label%20center#6c5419340d308e34)

Comment: +1 Nice question.  I didn't know you could have this level of control over placement of objects in ggplot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably unit for hjust is implicitly converted to numeric on the way to drawing.
So, try this:

```
grid.lines(c(0.5, 0.5))
grid.text("orzorzorz", y=0.4, hjust=unit(0.25, "npc"))
grid.text("orzorzorz", y=0.5, hjust=unit(0.25, "mm"))
grid.text("orzorzorz", y=0.6, hjust=unit(0.25, "cm"))
grid.text("orzorzorz", y=0.7, hjust=0.25)
```

and why the `u1+u2` induces the error is that:

```
> c(u1+u2)
$fname
[1] "+"

$arg1
[1] 0.5npc

$arg2
[1] 0.25npc
```

definitely this cannot be converted into numeric.

so, convertUnit is a workaround, but simply, `hjust = c(u1)+c(u2)` is sufficient.

Answer (score 2):

Baptiste's code includes a call to `convertUnit`.  Once you put this back into your code, it produces a plot:

```
p + opts(
  axis.title.x=theme_text(size=12,hjust=convertUnit(u1+u2, "npc", value=TRUE))
)
```

Comment: +1 Had to pick one, went with @koshke since his explained the source of the error.

Comment: Fair call.  @kohske gave more detail and explained it better than I did.